# Remove Empty Lines From Powershell Output

Tags: powershell

i've a little problem in powershell with all my cmd output.
I have to see on the screen a short cmd result.
In the specific this is one of my problem:

cmd

```
PS C:\C_Directory> ls -Filter *.err|Measure-Object -Line| fw


1
```

As you can see, the Format Wide output it's with more empity lines. How can i transfor this output in :

```
1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22311077/465053) which I found to be very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
 ls -Filter *.err|Measure-Object -Line | select -expand lines
```

Answer (score 4):

[Jeff Hicks](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JefferyHicks/posts) - a PowerShell MVP and more - has made a little filter to solve problems like this. [It's called scrub.](http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/2013/05/scrub-up-powershell-content/) Hope that helps.