# Remove blank lines in powershell output

Tags: powershell, output

I'm trying to remove blank lines before and after output but it's just not working. I tried Adding -NoNewLine after the very first Write-Host, but that only removes one blank line so far.

**Code:**

```
  $tag1 = "c91638"

    Write-Host "Operating System Information"


    $OSInfo = get-wmiobject -class win32_operatingsystem -computername $tag1 

    $OSInfo `
        | Format-List `
            @{Name="OS Name";Expression={$_.Caption}}, 
            @{Name="OS Boot Time";Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime)}}, 
            @{Name="OS Install Date";Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.InstallDate)}}; 

    Write-Host "Line test.."
```

**Outputs:**

```
Operating System Information


OS Name         : Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise 
OS Boot Time    : 8/27/2015 2:05:35 AM
OS Install Date : 4/4/2014 11:39:15 AM



Line test..
```

**What I want to do:**

```
Operating System Information

OS Name         : Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise 
OS Boot Time    : 8/27/2015 2:05:35 AM
OS Install Date : 4/4/2014 11:39:15 AM

Line test..
```

Comment: Something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22311077/465053) which I found to be very helpful.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
($OSInfo `
    | Format-List `
        @{Name="OS Name";Expression={$_.Caption}}, 
        @{Name="OS Boot Time";Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime)}}, 
        @{Name="OS Install Date";Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.InstallDate)}}  `
    | Out-String).Trim()
```

That'll clean up all the extraneous blank lines produced by `Format-List`. You may need to insert a couple of your own that you get to control.

Comment: I knew I was forgetting something.... Out-String. That works. I can add my own spaces.

Comment: It also trims leading spaces, which I don't want.  Any ideas?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski do you mean leading and trailing new lines rather than spaces?

Comment: No, it trims leading space characters when I only want it to trim blank lines.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski I can't repro. Can you post a screenshot on imgur or somewhere. Also what version of PowerShell?

Comment: Verison 7.2.  Here's an example. https://tio.run/##rYyxDYAwEMR6pjjRAAVULEHPAETkRCKFD8q/xPgBdsCVC8tXvlk0MKVxz4W19m2DDwtRkaIQQnrFjETnoxzQy@3UN3CGBT5LZ7idGKzE86Rvh2l9rR9q3X68bQ8

Answer (score 7):

Just to add a remark, because I see this being done all the time, even now - `Format-List` and `Format-Table` should **only** be used to output text in the console.

If you have objects to output as text files, CSV etc, then you simply should `Select-Object` to grab the objects you want rather than `ft` or `fl`. Then you can apply your `Out-String` if text formatting is required.

The above example should be:

```
($OSInfo `
| Select-Object `
    @{Name="OS Name";Expression={$_.Caption}}, 
    ... `
| Out-String).Trim()
```

Comment: I am outputting it in the console so it's fine also. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: What's the reason for that?

Comment: Because `Format-List` and `Format-Table` are for *formatting* output for *display* in the console. 

To select objects out of a pipeline, you should simply *select* them - then you're not dealing with whatever is going on under the hood with the formatting. 
*Formatting* the output for display on screen makes even less sense if you're exporting to CSV - the CSV is the format you want. `Format-Table` is a complete waste of time - `Select`, then `Export-CSV` does your formatting.

Comment: As I often see "The above example should be:" no longer has any relevant/context for "above" as questions get voted up/down.  Perhaps you can edit it and add a link to whatever that WAS at Sep 18, 2016 at 5:38.

Answer (score 2):

Using `.Trim()` goes too far in that it deletes leading & trailing spaces as well as blank lines.  If you want to delete only blank lines, try this, after any code that results in a string, do:

`` $result.Trim("`r","`n") ``

Or for many strings, e.g. after `Format-Table` or similar:

`` $results | Format-Table | Out-String | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim("`r","`n") } ``

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this :

```powershell
$result=yourCommandHere | Out-String
$result.Trim()
```

Or in a single line without using a variable :

```powershell
(yourCommandHere | Out-String).Trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an all-in-one function to easily write list (as output result), blank lines are removed, it can be piped.
2 examples of use shown below
Hope this help

```
function Write-List {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)][array] $Array,
        [string]$Prefixe,
        [bool]$Numbering = $False
    )
    if ($Numbering) { 
        $NumberOfDigit = $($Array.Count).ToString().Length

        $Array | Format-List | Out-String -Stream | ForEach-Object -Process {
            if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)) {
                "$Prefixe# {0,$NumberOfDigit} : {1}" -f (++$Index), $_
            }
        }
    } else {
        $Array | Format-List | Out-String -Stream | ForEach-Object -Process {
            if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)) {
                "$Prefixe{0}" -f $_
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example #1 :

```
Write-List @("titi", "toto", "tata", "titi", "toto", "tata", "titi", "toto", "tata", "titi", "toto", "tata") -Numbering $True
#  1 : titi
#  2 : toto
#  3 : tata
#  4 : titi
#  5 : toto
#  6 : tata
#  7 : titi
#  8 : toto
#  9 : tata
# 10 : titi
# 11 : toto
# 12 : tata
```

Example #2 :

```
Get-Service -Name "*openvpn*" | Select-Object DisplayName,Name,Status,StartType | Write-List -Prefixe " - "
 - DisplayName : OpenVPN Interactive Service
 - Name        : OpenVPNServiceInteractive
 - Status      : Running
 - StartType   : Automatic
```